# Table Tennis exercises by yourself and without a table?

Tags: training, table-tennis

Is it possible to improve your table tennis skills by yourself without a table as well?

If so are there exercises that one could do to improve your table tennis skills by yourself?

Comment: I would take a look here for some ideas http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/50/recommended-drills-to-help-keep-your-eye-on-the-ball

Comment: @MarcusSwope i thought about that but i'd rather use a table tennis racquet ;). I guess i could do that to the end of the bat.

Comment: Update: found a youtube video on this - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8Pv8vWdyL8&feature=relmfu

Comment: Found another exersize: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOvEOFO9YYM&feature=g-vrec&context=G29d6775RVAAAAAAAAAA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[One article](http://tabletennis.about.com/od/trainingbyyourself/a/trainbyyourself.htm) discussed various solo table tennis training drills. Topics included:

> - Serving Practice
> - Shadow Play and Ghosting
> - Solo Footwork Drills
> - Video Footage Analysis
> - Table Tennis Robots

Each topic had several practical pointers and tips.

One [table tennis forum post](http://www.tabletennisforum.gr/forum_posts.asp?TID=5007&title=solo-drills) dealt with this question and had two suggestions:

1. Shadow play (mentioned in the first article above)
2. Purchase a return board

Regarding the return board, one poster noted:

> return boards have proper rubber on them, and can actually help you,
>   unlike folding the table up

These resources suggest that there's a wide range of drills that one can do without purchasing any equipment - at minimum shadow play and footwork drills can be done without *any* equipment. At the high end, buying a robot or doing video analysis can be costly, but can provide good returns if solo practice is very important.

Comment: Ah great idea return board